# FireStore Multi-Group Permission Management

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Can Firestore security rules manage security permissions across multiple groups?
For example, suppose there are individual users Group1 and Group2.

```
Group1 {
  groupId: string
  groupMembers {
    userId: string 
  }
}

Group2 {
  groupId: string
  groupMembers {
    userId: string
  }
}
```

Is it possible to manage chat permissions shared by two Groups?

```
Chat1 {
  editerGroupIds: [groupId, groupId]
}
```

I thought it would be possible if I could loop the List but Firestore did not support it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to loop over things in security rules, as that would never scale. You'll typically want to store the group membership in a way that allows you to implement an `in` or an `exists` check in your security rules. So that means you'd keep a collection with UID-keyed documented, or an array with UIDs for your group.